# Programmatically modify SQLite database without using SQL

Tags: sql, c, sqlite

I am using the C API to SQLite and the only way to modify the DB seems to be with SQL statements as strings. For example, the documentation shows a code example which just passes a command line string to the engine via an `exec` function call:

```
rc = sqlite3_exec(db, argv[2], callback, 0, &zErrMsg);
```

I don't want to be constructing strings and passing them to an interpreter, not the least because of security issues, but also because I don't want to be monkeying around cobbling strings and escape sequences together.

Are there SQLite functions which allow me to manipulate the database directly without making an SQL string?

Comment: You always have to create a string to describe the operation, but you can use "compiled" statements to (when properly used) eliminate any chance of "SQL injection" and to facilitate specifying variable parms.

Comment: Well, *don't* go "monkeying around cobbling strings and escape sequences together" - that is what placeholders / prepared statements are for. Problem solved.

Comment: There *may* be a way to create/invoke the internal "programs/DSL" used by SQLite, but that is for research/learning/fun purposes only and *not* to avoid this "issue"; it just wouldn't be practical to describe the operations. It may be more practical to go the other way: use a DSL/tree-to-SQL (with placeholders/bindings) library/transformation. I'm not sure what there is for C but there are many examples in other languages and I've created similar high-level SQL generators.

Answer (score 1):

`sqlite_exec` supports only a single SQL string.
If you really want to use it, you can safely cobble strings and escape sequences together with [sqlite3_mprintf](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/mprintf.html).

To avoid monkeying around cobbling strings and escape sequences together, use prepared statements and parameter binding:

```
sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
const char *sql = "UPDATE MyTable SET Name = ? WHERE ID = ?";
rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, -1, &stmt, NULL);
if (rc == SQLITE_OK) {
    sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, "Tyler Durden", -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_int (stmt, 2, 1655700);
    rc = sqlite3_step(stmt);
    if (rc != SQLITE_DONE)
        ; // error
    sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

SQLite is specifically designed to be an SQL database, which means that you use SQL as the language do interact with the database and let the database care about any internals, optimizations etc. SQL is defined as a language independent from the lower level implementation and not as an API to an implementation.

But maybe your requirements do not need an SQL database at all. In this case there are several simpler databases (like BerkeleyDB) which only store a value to a key and which have APIs for several programming languages.